# Is there any way to learn which databases I have an authority?

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I login sql server. I see many databases but I dont have an accessing some databases. So I wanna list only accessing databases using linkedname. I wanna run this code

```
select name
FROM [linkedname].sys.sysdatabases
WHERE HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1"
```

Comment: You can use `EXEC (..) AT [linkedname]` to perform any given query remotely. Use that instead of accessing `sysdatabases` directly through a remote name.

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL**

```
SELECT name, HAS_DBACCESS(name) FROM sys.databases;
```

**SQL Server**

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
```

Or any of the following ways

```
SHOW GRANTS;
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER();
```

Result

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for jeffrey@localhost                                     |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `jeffrey`@`localhost`                      |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON `db1`.* TO `jeffrey`@`localhost` |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

References : [dev.mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-grants.html)

Comment: Yeah ıt is working when I run this code in my local sql server. But it is not working when I using linked server.   SELECT name, HAS_DBACCESS(name) FROM [linkedname].master.sys.databases  this code is not working.

Comment: check this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-grants.html

Answer (score 0):

> you can find the list of database which you have access.

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.sysdatabases
WHERE HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1
```

Comment: Yeah ıt is working when I run this code in my local sql server. But it is not working when I using linked server.   SELECT name
FROM [linkedname].master.sys.sysdatabases
WHERE HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1  this code is not working