# Is there any way to list only accessing databases using linked server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I login sql server. I see many databases but I dont have an accessing some databases. So I wanna list only accessing databases using linkedname.

```
select name FROM sys.sysdatabases WHERE HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1
```

I run this code localy it is working. But  I wanna run this code

```
select name FROM [linkedname].sys.sysdatabases WHERE HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1
```

it is not working.

Comment: You should really mark the answer you got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56848966/3484879) as the solution, as you're clearly using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[linkedname].sys.sysdatabases` would reference the **database** `linkedname`, not the server.

You need to use 4 part naming `LinkedServerName.DatabaseName.SchemaName.ObjectName`. For your example, that would be: `[linkedname].master.sys.sysdatabases`

Because, however, (as Dan Guzman pointed out) this is a linked query, `HAS_DBACCESS` will be run locally. You can get around this by using `OPENQUERY`:

```
SELECT [name]
FROM OPENQUERY(linkedname,N'SELECT [name] FROM master.sys.sysdatabases WHERE HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1;');
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the `HAS_DBACCESS` function will be evaluated on the local server with this method using the remote database name.

Comment: Was blinded by the typographical error that I didn't notice the use of `HAS_DBACCESS`. You're right @DanGuzman .